# There Is No Tokenizer Extension In XAMPP PHP

Tags: php, xampp, extension

My laptop runs on Windows 7 with XAMMP installed. My PHP version is 7.3.0. 
From the documentation on the [Tokenizer PHP Extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.installation.php), it states that:

> The Windows version of PHP has built-in support for this extension. You do not need to load any additional extensions in order to use these functions.

But when I open my `php.ini` file and `php\ext` directory, the extension doesn't exist.

Here are screenshots of my `php.ini` file and `ext` directory:

*ex. php.ini File*

[image: php.ini file]

*ex. Ext Directory*

[image: ext directory].

Does XAMMP not include this extension and do I need to download the `.dll` file online (which I think is potentially harmful)? Or is it intentionally not listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does XAMMP not include this extension and do I need to download the `.dll` file online (which I think is potentially harmful)?

In this case, per the [official documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.installation.php) you referenced, "built-in" means "not compiled as a separate `.dll`". So there is nothing to download, nothing to uncomment in `php.ini` and nothing to see in the `ext` directory.

If you run `phpinfo()`, you should see the `tokenizer` extension listed and `enabled`:

[image: Tokenizer Extension - phpinfo() - Screenshot]

So, to answer your question, it is (effectively) "intentionally not listed".

---

**Notes**

To run `phpinfo()`:

1. Create a text document with `<?php phpinfo()?>` in it.
2. Save this file with a `.php` extension (e.g. `phpinfo.php`).
3. Place this `.php` file in a directory that is allowed to execute scripts (possibly your root `htdocs` directory) and go to e.g. `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`.

---

Comment: that explains it... thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. =)